# How to show / hide a chart using a button (Apps Script) on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I want to use a Button to Show / Hide a Chart on Google Sheets. Is it possible to do so, if yes...Someone please guide me how to achieve this using Apps Script.

I searched a lot in google but didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible but why not having the chart on a different sheet and the button hide/unhide the other sheet (and display a link to it for quicker access) ?

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion...